# Get total count rows for Pageable custom query in Spring repository

Tags: java, pagination, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I implement pagination like this:

```
List<Products> products = productRepository.findAllProducts(productsRequest.getInitiatorType(), "ACTIVE",
      new PageRequest(page, 100, Sort.Direction.DESC, "insertDate"));
```

But how can I get Total size for this query? Only duplicate query like this?

```
  @Query("SELECT t FROM Products t WHERE t.isApproved = true AND t.partnerId = ?1 AND t.categories.status = ?2")
  List<OpcClProducts> findAllOpcClProducts(String senderId, String status, Pageable pageable);


  @Query("SELECT COUNT(t) FROM Products t WHERE t.isApproved = true AND t.partnerId = ?1 AND t.categories.status = ?2")
  long getTotalCount(String senderId, String status);
```

And call 2 query: for totalCount and for data?

Comment: Try changing your object to Page<Products>

Comment: And while you're at it, rename the entity to `Product`. An instance is one Product. String isn't named Strings, because each instance is one String.

Comment: @andrewTobilko Thank you for reminding me! I was not 100% sure about that ^^'

Comment: @ip696 have a look at the answer provided by Noixes. Does it resolve the issue?

Comment: So there is a brain out there that thinks the same way mine does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try changing your object to

```
Page<Products> p ..
```

p should have the information you are looking for. :)
(Posted here because they wanted me to)
^^'

Comment: I haven't checked it out, but I believe it's the right answer. +1

Comment: page.getTotalElements() will give you number of rows returned by query 
page.getTotalPages()   will give  you number of pages  with respect to page size (item per page you configured)

Comment: absolutely useful information that came first in my search results...

Comment: Using spring boot data jdbc, if your interface extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` and the query returns more than one result, you get `org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 50`